# How does the Now() class works?

Tags: django

So I found a way to get the database timestamp and I tried to implement it for the first time

```
def __str__(self):


        is_exp = 'EXPIRED' if self.date_created > Now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10) else 'AVAIL'

        return '{} {}'.format(self.code, is_exp)
```

the code is used to see if a token is expired. I ran this code an it gave me this errpr

```
'>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'CombinedExpression'
```

Now I've found some solution I've not tried yet but my main goal here is to understand what's going on.

Comment: Your syntax is just not correct. First, you should add parenthesis for the condition of your `if` statement. Second, if the condition is checked, there is no action, but directly the `else` part.

Comment: @Christophe That's entirely incorrect. That's a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

Comment: Oh so sorry, I did not know

Answer (score 4):

[`Now()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/functions/datetime.py#L206) is a database operation that turns into an SQL function call (or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` reference) when sent to the database. You can only use it in queries.

The function `now()` (`django.utils.timezone.now()`), that returns the current time as a datetime with a correct timezone, is what you use outside of a database context (eg. here).